# Need Amazon SP- API replacment reports list

Tags: amazon-selling-partner-api

As per Amazon SP APi documentation (https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/changelog/deprecation-notice-suppressed-listings-reports-and-fba-inventory-reports ) below Reports will no longer be available,

Effective  January 31, 2023, the following reports will no longer be available in MWS or Selling Partner API:

```
GET_FBA_FULFILLMENT_CURRENT_INVENTORY_DATA
GET_FBA_FULFILLMENT_MONTHLY_INVENTORY_DATA
GET_FBA_FULFILLMENT_INVENTORY_ADJUSTMENTS_DATA
GET_FBA_RECONCILIATION_REPORT_DATA
GET_FBA_FULFILLMENT_INVENTORY_SUMMARY_DATA
GET_FBA_FULFILLMENT_INVENTORY_RECEIPTS_DATA
```

Can Anybody please help me to send the replacement reports list for each of the above list? What new report I can use for each individaual report included above.

I checked report types in Amazon API document at : https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/report-type-values#inventory-reports , But not found any help what exact report is there for each single report. I did lot of google search but no help.

Answer (score 2):

As of January 31, 2023, Amazon is discontinuing several FBA Inventory Reports in MWS and the Selling Partner API, including:

- GET_FBA_FULFILLMENT_CURRENT_INVENTORY_DATA
- GET_FBA_FULFILLMENT_MONTHLY_INVENTORY_DATA
- GET_FBA_FULFILLMENT_INVENTORY_ADJUSTMENTS_DATA
- GET_FBA_RECONCILIATION_REPORT_DATA
- GET_FBA_FULFILLMENT_INVENTORY_SUMMARY_DATA
- GET_FBA_FULFILLMENT_INVENTORY_RECEIPTS_DATA

Amazon suggests transitioning to the replacement reports:

**GET_LEDGER_SUMMARY_VIEW_DATA**: Offers comprehensive inventory reconciliation, including starting and ending balances, orders, returns, and more.

**GET_LEDGER_DETAIL_VIEW_DATA**: Provides detailed insights into inventory movements, covering sales, returns, removals, damages, losses, and finds.

To get the data you're looking for, consider comparing the results of these new reports with data from the previous reports. This can help you seamlessly transition and maintain continuity in your inventory management and data tracking. For more details, refer to Amazon's official documentation for updates.